# Publish NuGet packages with Fake

Tags: .net, f#-fake

I'm working on a .NET project that has a few libraries that I want to build, package and publish as NuGet packages by using Fake.

However, I have not found a valuable resource that explains to me how to achieve this.

What are the required steps to make this work?

Comment: Is the library using fake?

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the Fake API docs are missing this content. There is even a broken link at the time of writing which supposedly has Nuget publishing instructions.

If it helps you, the missing page used to exist last year. You can view it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20220702024513/https://fake.build/dotnet-nuget.html

I can't offer any more than that since I haven't worked with Fake myself.